# Matplotlib plotting two graphs on top of each other in AWS Lambda

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, matplotlib, aws-lambda

I am using the following code to create two graphs and save them as PNG files in S3 buckets. The first graph is a pie graph and the second graph is a bar chart. The pie chart is working perfectly, however the bar chart is being printed ON TOP of the pie chart. I am not very familiar with the code I am using to create the plots and save them in AWS, so I would appreciate help. Code below:

```
import json
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
from io import StringIO, BytesIO


s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    today=datetime.date.today()
    
    bucket_name = 'streetcatexamplebucket1'
    file_name = '11122212 - analytics.csv'
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    
    df = pd.read_csv(response['Body'], sep=',')
    
    firmcount = df["Firm"].value_counts()
    
    pieDF = df["Firm"].value_counts().rename_axis("sub_firm_values").reset_index(name="count")
    
    x = pieDF["count"].to_numpy()
    y = pieDF["sub_firm_values"].to_numpy()
    
    
    pie_image_file_name = "11122212 - pie chart.png"
    plt.title("Firm Outreach Distribution")
    img_data = BytesIO()
    plt.pie(x, labels = y)
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig(img_data, format='png')
    img_data.seek(0)
    bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name)
    bucket.put_object(Body=img_data, ContentType='image/png', Key=pie_image_file_name)
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    #define the variables associated with the user profile CSV file
    #bucket_name = 'streetcatexamplebucket1'
    user_file_name = '11122212.csv'
    response2 = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=user_file_name)
    
    #read the user profile CSV file into a pandas dataframe
    userDF = pd.read_csv(response2['Body'], sep=',')
    
    userdate = userDF.iloc[0,6]
    userenddate = today
    userenddate = userenddate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    
    
    #define the variables associated with the analytics CSV file
    #bucket_name = 'streetcatexamplebucket1'
    #file_name = '11122212 - analytics.csv'
    response3 = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_name)
    
    #read the analytics CSV file into a pandas dataframe
    databaseDF = pd.read_csv(response3['Body'], sep=',')
    DF2 = databaseDF.loc[(databaseDF["Date Sent"] >= str(userdate)) & (databaseDF["Date Sent"] <= str(userenddate))]
    
    #calculating the values to use in the date delta logic
    startyear = userdate[0:4]
    startmonth = userdate[5:7]
    startday = userdate[8:10]

    #calculating the values to use in the date delta logic
    endyear = userenddate[0:4]
    endmonth = userenddate[5:7]
    endday = userenddate[8:10]
    
    #this is the list of dates that are one week apart from one another within the date range specified by the user
    sections = []


    #year month day format
    barstartdate = datetime.date(int(startyear),int(startmonth),int(startday))
    #year month day format
    barenddate = datetime.date(int(endyear),int(endmonth),int(endday))
    #delta time
    delta = datetime.timedelta(days=7)
    #iterate over range of dates
    #print dates in one week intervals
    #add these dates to the list called sections
    while (barstartdate <= barenddate):
        print(barstartdate, end="\n")
        sections.append(barstartdate.isoformat())
        barstartdate += delta
    sections.append(barenddate.isoformat())
    
    #two additional lists that contain the count of emails sent in different time intervals and the labels of those time intervals
    sectioncount = []
    sectionlabels = []
    
    #for loop cycling through the number of week long intervals between the dates input by the user
    #each time through the for loop the count is added to the list called sectioncount and the date label is added to the list called sectionlabels
    for i in range(0,(len(sections)-1)):
        barDF = databaseDF.loc[(databaseDF["Date Sent"] >= str(sections[i])) & (databaseDF["Date Sent"] <= str(sections[i+1]))]
        emailcount = barDF.shape[0]
        sectioncount.append(emailcount)
        sectionlabels.append(sections[i] + " - " + sections[i+1])
        
    chartsectioncount = np.array(sectioncount)
    chartsectionlabels = np.array(sectionlabels)
    
    bar_image_file_name = '11122212' + " - timebarchart.png"
    img_data = BytesIO()
    plt.title("Email Count Over Time (Weeks)")
    plt.bar(chartsectionlabels,chartsectioncount)
    plt.xticks(rotation=30, ha='right')
    plt.tight_layout()
    #plt.show()
    plt.savefig(img_data, format='png')
    img_data.seek(0)
    bucket = boto3.resource('s3').Bucket(bucket_name)
    bucket.put_object(Body=img_data, ContentType='image/png', Key=bar_image_file_name)
```

I tried messing around with the img_data variables but could not figure it out. Essentially I am trying to "clear the canvas" before making the second chart or change one of the variables that makes the second plot completely individual from the first.